# Display Set Default SMS App Dialog

Tags: android

In my app I change the default SMS app to insert/remove messages to/from the SMS Database.
For do this I become the default SMS app.
At the end, I restore the previous default app. 
But in the case, of a user, by error, selects my app has the default SMS app, I need to display the chooser at startup.
I know how display the set default SMS app yes/no dialog, but I need to display a dialog with all SMS capable apps, like the dialog that is displayed at Android Settings.
It is possible? 
Thanks